# Rails with devise, Could not find a strategy with name `LinkedinOauth2'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, linkedin-api

I used gem:

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-linkedin-oauth2'
```

And config my devise:

```
require 'omniauth-linkedin-oauth2'
config.omniauth :linkedin_oauth2, ENV['LINKED_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['LINKED_CLIENT_SECRET']
```

I show me error:

```
Could not find a strategy with name `LinkedinOauth2'
```

Before that, i used: `gem 'linkedin'` and `config.omniauth :linkedin, ENV['LINKED_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['LINKED_CLIENT_SECRET']` , it works.
Any idead? Please help me!

Comment: hello, please give us more information. Right now I have no idea

Comment: Can you show us your `config/initializers/omniauth.rb` file?

Comment: I fixed this error by used: `require 'omniauth-linkedin-oauth2'` and `config.omniauth :linkedin, ENV['LINKED_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['LINKED_CLIENT_SECRET']`, but it now show me: `omniauth: (linkedin) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, invalid_request: missing required parameters, includes an invalid parameter value, parameter more than once. : Unable to retrieve access token : appId or redirect uri does not match authorization code or authorization code expired`. So sad :(

Comment: @AvadaKedavra did you figure this out? I'm getting this error too.

Comment: For older rails apps, you may need to set `strategy_class` option explicitly. 
 i.e. `strategy_class: OmniAuth::Strategies::LinkedIn` (with the `config.omniauth`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in the **devise.rb** file with the omniauth configuration.
Change

```
require 'omniauth-linkedin-oauth2'
config.omniauth :linkedin_oauth2, ENV['LINKED_CLIENT_ID'], 
ENV['LINKED_CLIENT_SECRET']
```

**TO**

```
require 'omniauth-linkedin'
config.omniauth :linkedin_oauth2, ENV['LINKED_CLIENT_ID'], 
ENV['LINKED_CLIENT_SECRET']
```

Need to remove oauth2 from require.